# Windows PS and WSL2 Can't seem to send icmp echo requests or download anything

Tags: linux, windows, internet, wsl2

I updated to *Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.264]* (the new May 2004 update) in order to check out wsl2 and see all the new features.  I had wsl1 set up and working as I like to use it for IRC often.  Everything was working well before the update.

So I updated to 2004 and followed the installation steps for wsl2 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and everything was going smoothly.  No errors occured.

Then I tried to `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and the results are as follows:

```
[sudo] password for USERNAME:
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

ok... so there's a problem.  So it must be to do with the wireless, right?  I do a `lshw -C network`

```
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:15:5d:f3:23:81
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=hv_netvsc duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=172.28.70.182 link=yes multicast=yes speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: dummy0
       serial: 0e:25:ec:70:65:ec
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=dummy driverversion=1.0
  *-network:2 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: bond0
       serial: da:9c:6a:d4:f2:16
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bonding driverversion=3.7.1 firmware=2 link=no master=yes multicast=yes
```

so it looks like it sees my wireless card... so next I try a `ping` and all I get is `Temporary failure in name resolution`

I followed the solution here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-resolve-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-issue

It only works though if you write the following to `/etc/wsl.conf`

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

so make sure you `sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`, paste that in there, CTRL+O and CTRL+X and then exit and in powershell `wsl --shutdown` and then start it again.  This fixed it for me.

Let this be documentation for anyone else who faces this problem.